# Gmail API java update draft using MimeMessage

Tags: java, gmail, gmail-api

Google provides the following code to get a gmail draft

```
public static Draft getDraft(Gmail service, String userId, String draftId)
  throws IOException {
Draft draft = service.users().drafts().get(userId, draftId).execute();
Message message = draft.getMessage();

System.out.println("Draft id: " + draft.getId() + "\nDraft Message:\n"
    + message.toPrettyString());

return draft;}
```

My question is : Can I get a MimeMessage from the Message? If I could, I would update this MimeMessage with multiple attachments. Or if anyone else knows how to update a draft with multiple attachments, please advice.

Comment: You can get the Mime message contained in the draft by calling drafts.get https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/get with format=raw. For more information on updating drafts you can check this link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts

Comment: Thank you, I have already read all there is. Any other suggestions?